# cursor/other solution for complex insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, cursor

I have two relevant tables:

```
create table readData
(
    readDataId int identity primary key,    
    dp4 varchar(300),
    fields....

);
create table calculatedData
(
    calculatedDataId int identity primary key,
    readDataId int foreign key references readData (readDataId),
    fields...
    calculated field 1,
    calculated field 2,
    calculated field 3,
    etc..
);
```

the dp4 field in the table looks like this: '138,73,117,112'.

I have a stored procedure that handles it all. data is being inserted into some fields of the calculatedData table with insert into from select, and then I need to breakdown the dp4 field into four variables, make some calculations and updae the calculated fields in calculatedData.
This has to be done for each row.

I wrote a function to breakdown the dp4 field and then I use it inside a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON calculatedData
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @readDataId int;
    declare @dp4 varchar(300);
    declare @dp0 varchar(300);
    declare @dp1 varchar(300);
    declare @dp2 varchar(300);
    declare @dp3 varchar(300);
    declare @dp0Int int;
    declare @dp1Int int;
    declare @dp2Int int;
    declare @dp3Int int;

    select @readDataId=i.readDataId from inserted i;
    select @dp4=dp4 from readData where readDataId=@readDataId;

    select @dp0=dp from dbo.splitstring(@dp4) where id=1;
    select @dp1=dp from dbo.splitstring(@dp4) where id=2;
    select @dp2=dp from dbo.splitstring(@dp4) where id=3;
    select @dp3=dp from dbo.splitstring(@dp4) where id=4;

    select @dp0Int=cast(@dp0 as int);
    select @dp1Int=cast(@dp1 as int);
    select @dp2Int=cast(@dp2 as int);
    select @dp3Int=cast(@dp3 as int);

    update calculatedData set TotalReads=@dp0Int+@dp1Int+@dp2Int+@dp3Int where readDataId=@readDataId
GO
```

That's only one calculation with this field^^

Only when I ran it, I realized the trigger happens not each row, but each statement., so for example the TotalReads field is beig updated only for one row. 
So I started reading about cursors but couldn't write one to handle my needs.

I would appriciate any help. and if there is a more efficient way of doing this without cursor, I would love to know.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

this is the splitString function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([id] [int] identity,[dp] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

Comment: poor schema: 1)  Store only one value in column dp4 instead of storing comma separated list. 2)  Instead of a `calculatedData` table create a calculatedData `View` or a `Table-Valued-Function` which doesn't store any data but calculate data on the fly.

Comment: When you say *complex insert trigger* and you mention *cursor* in the same sentence, it makes me shiver. A trigger should be **as small and lean** as possible - it should ***NOT*** do any extensive processing! The trigger is executing in the context of the statement that triggers it - if it uses up a lot of time, your app becomes sluggish and slow. **Don't do this!** Instead: make a note into a separate table that rows with ID 4, 7, 23, 37 (or whatever they will be) need to be updated and that's all. Let a separate, scheduled process then do the calculations + updates

Comment: thank you for your comments. This trigger only happens once when insertion is happening. so maybe it wouldn't be such a bad idea.            @marc_s, you mean create a table with all the dp4 values? and then? could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts here:

```
select @readDataId=i.readDataId from inserted i;
```

For efficiency, SQL Server doesn't fire the trigger every time a row is inserted. It will fire the trigger once for for multiple rows. I never dug deep enough to find out what the thresholds were so I simply assumed that there will be multiple rows in the `inserted` table.

Cursor is a big bad word in the relational world. Almost every time you think about using it, you are doing it wrong. Here's a improvised version based on your code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON calculatedData
FOR INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @tmp TABLE (
        readDataID int,
        dp int
    )

    INSERT INTO @tmp (readDataID, dp)
        SELECT      i.readDataID,
                    CAST(s.dp AS INT)
        FROM        inserted i
        CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(i.dp4) s

    UPDATE c
        SET c.TotalReads = SUM(tmp.dp)
        FROM @tmp tmp
        INNER JOIN calculatedData c ON tmp.readDataId = c.readDataID
GO
```

I haven't tested this code due to the lack of data. It should give you a pointer. Please post some data if you need help finishing off the above.

Comment: thanks for that, but it tells me that I cannot use SUM in update statement. so I tried to get some as a table variable and it set to whole column to a wrong sum of view. this procedure only happens in an insertion. so it's rarely used.. Can you help me with declaring a cursor? also I edited and copied the function. maybe that will help. thanks! : ]